# cutomtkinter, matplotlib no x,y - xaxis and x,y - labels-> only graph and grid visible?

Tags: python, matplotlib, customtkinter

I am trying to create a virtual signal-generator(function-generator) - GUI with the cutomtkinter, matplotlib libs. The graph should be updated after a button click continuosly. I have managed to get a graph updated continuosly with a grid in the backround, but the  x,y  - xaxis  and x,y - labels are not visible?

Here is the button code:

```py
def update_window(self):
    startx, endx = 0, SIG_ARRAY_SIZE + 1
    starty, endy = -SIG_ARRAY_DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE - 1, SIG_ARRAY_DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE + 1
    plt.axis([startx, endx, starty, endy])
    plt.xlabel('t [msec]')
    plt.ylabel('U [V]')
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    while True:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        ax.set_title('Signal')
        plt.axis([startx, endx, starty, endy])
        ax.set_xlabel('t [msec]', fontweight=12)
        ax.set_ylabel('U [V]', fontsize=12)

        x_val: list = list(range(0, SIG_ARRAY_SIZE, 1))
        # generating random data values
        sig.sigSetSignalName("Sinus")
        sig.sigCreateSinusSignal()
        y_val = sig.sig_arr

        ax.axis([startx, endx, starty, endy])
        ax.grid()

        line, = plt.plot(x_val, y_val, 'b')

        fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, bottom=0, top=1, wspace=0, hspace=0)
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=self.root)
        canvas.draw()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().place(relx=0.33, rely=0.025)

        plt.close(fig)
        self.root.update()
```

Sinus signal capture:

[image: sinus signal capture]

and here is the whole code of the module:

```py
from  signal_generator import SignalGenerator
import tkinter as tk
import customtkinter as ctk
from tkinter import Button
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from operator import methodcaller
import time


SIG_ARRAY_SIZE = 360
SIG_ARRAY_DEFAULT_VALUE = 5
SIG_ARRAY_DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE = 10

sig: SignalGenerator = SignalGenerator()

class ctkApp:

    def __init__(self):
        ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")
        self.root = ctk.CTk()
        self.root.geometry("1000x600+200x200")
        self.root.title("Signal Scope")
        self.root.update()
        self.frame = ctk.CTkFrame(master=self.root,
                                  height=self.root.winfo_height() * 0.95,
                                  width=self.root.winfo_width() * 0.66,
                                  fg_color="darkblue")
        self.frame.place(relx=0.33, rely=0.025)
        self.input = ctk.CTkEntry(master=self.root,
                                  placeholder_text=100,
                                  justify='center',
                                  width=300,
                                  height=50,
                                  fg_color="darkblue")
        self.input.insert(0, 100)
        self.input.place(relx=0.025, rely=0.5)
        self.slider = ctk.CTkSlider(master=self.root,
                                    width=300,
                                    height=20,
                                    from_=1,
                                    to=1000,
                                    number_of_steps=999,
                                    command=self.update_surface)
        self.slider.place(relx=0.025, rely=0.75)
        self.button = ctk.CTkButton(master=self.root,
                                    text="Update Graph",
                                    width=300,
                                    height=50,
                                    command=self.update_window)
        self.button.place(relx=0.025, rely=0.25)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def update_window(self):
        startx, endx = 0, SIG_ARRAY_SIZE + 1
        starty, endy = -SIG_ARRAY_DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE - 1, SIG_ARRAY_DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE + 1
        plt.axis([startx, endx, starty, endy])
        plt.xlabel('t [msec]')
        plt.ylabel('U [V]')
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

        while True:
            fig, ax = plt.subplots()
            ax.set_title('Signal')
            plt.axis([startx, endx, starty, endy])
            ax.set_xlabel('t [msec]', fontweight=12)
            ax.set_ylabel('U [V]', fontsize=12)

            x_val: list = list(range(0, SIG_ARRAY_SIZE, 1))
            # generating random data values
            sig.sigSetSignalName("Sinus")
            sig.sigCreateSinusSignal()
            y_val = sig.sig_arr

            ax.axis([startx, endx, starty, endy])
            ax.grid()

            line, = plt.plot(x_val, y_val, 'b')

            fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, bottom=0, top=1, wspace=0, hspace=0)
            canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=self.root)
            canvas.draw()
            canvas.get_tk_widget().place(relx=0.33, rely=0.025)

            plt.close(fig)
            self.root.update()

    def update_surface(self, other):

            fig, ax = plt.subplots()
            fig.set_size_inches(11, 5.3)
            ax.scatter(x, y, s * self.slider.get(), c)
            ax.axis("off")
            fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, bottom=0, top=1, wspace=0, hspace=0)
            canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=self.root)
            canvas.draw()
            canvas.get_tk_widget().place(relx=0.33, rely=0.025)
            self.root.update()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    CTK_Window = ctkApp()
```

I am trying to create a virtual signal-generator(function-generator) - GUI with the cutomtkinter, matplotlib libs. The graph should be updated after a button click continuosly. I have managed to get a graph updated continuosly with a grid in the backround, but the  x,y  - xaxis  and x,y - labels are not visible?